# Custom Login on Community Site redirecting to Custom Login Page

Tags: customer-community, login

I tried following this [resource](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/0/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf) with some code from [here](http://www.forcetree.com/2014/05/salesforce-login-page-custom-login-page.html). Under Communities > Settings > Administration I have the login page set to Custom_Sign_In. I am sent to my custom signin page when appropriate, but when I sign in, I get sent back to my custom sign in page and the URL looks like this:

```
https://developer-edition.na34.force.com/wpu/Custom_Sign_In?refURL=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper-edition.na34.force.com%2Fwpu%2FCustom_Sign_In
```

I want it to go to `https://developer-edition.na34.force.com/wpu/` and I cannot figure out how to do so. I am assuming there is a problem with my controller, but I don't know what.

When I change the login page to the default, I can log in without problems.

Here's my code:

Custom Sign In Page

```
<apex:page applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" controller="CustomLoginController"
title="{!$Label.site.site_login}">

        <apex:form forceSSL="true" styleClass="form-signin col-md-4 col-centered">
            <apex:actionFunction name="login" action="{!login}" />
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
            <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" />
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Sign in" styleClass="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" action="{!login}" />

        </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

CustomLoginController

```
public class CustomLoginController {

    public String username{get; set;}
    public String password {get; set;}

    public pageReference login()
        {  
            return Site.login(username,password,null);
    }
}
```

CommunitiesLogin Page

```
<apex:page id="loginPage" controller="CommunitiesLoginController" action="{!forwardToCustomAuthPage}" title="{!$Label.site.site_login}">
</apex:page>
```

CommunitiesLanding Page

```
<apex:page id="communitiesLandingPage" controller="CommunitiesLandingController" action="{!forwardToCustomAuthPage}" title="{!$Label.site.site_login}">
</apex:page>
```

CommunitiesLoginController

```
global with sharing class CommunitiesLoginController {

    global CommunitiesLoginController () {}

    global PageReference forwardToAuthPage() {
        String startUrl = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('startURL');
        String displayType = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('display');
        return Network.forwardToAuthPage(startUrl, displayType);
    }

     global PageReference forwardToCustomAuthPage() {
        String startUrl = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('startURL');
        return new PageReference(Site.getPathPrefix() + '/Custom_Sign_In?startURL=' +
        EncodingUtil.urlEncode(startURL, 'UTF-8'));
    }

}
```

CommunitiesLandingController

```
public with sharing class CommunitiesLandingController {


    public PageReference forwardToStartPage() {
        return Network.communitiesLanding();
    }

    public PageReference forwardToCustomAuthPage() {
        String startUrl = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('startURL');
        return new PageReference(Site.getPathPrefix() + '/Custom_Sign_In?startURL=' +
        EncodingUtil.urlEncode(startURL, 'UTF-8'));
    }


    public CommunitiesLandingController() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller was fine. The fault was in my visualforce page. Here is the corrected code:

```
<apex:form forceSSL="true" styleClass="form-signin col-md-4 col-centered">
        <apex:actionFunction name="login" action="{!login}" />
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <label for="username" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <apex:inputText value="{!username}" id="username" styleClass="form-control" html-placeholder="Email" />
        <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <apex:inputSecret id="password" value="{!password}" styleClass="form-control" html-placeholder="Password" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Sign in" styleClass="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" action="{!login}" />

    </apex:form>
```